# Out of the box approval workflow suddenly failed on start (retrying)

Tags: workflow, approval-process

SharePoint 2010. I've been using out of the box approval workflow for several month now. I did some minor changes to it, like to who and when emails should be send, but that's all.

Then out of a sudden it stopped working. New request status is "Failed on start (retrying)". Sometimes (!) status is "In Progress", but no tasks are created. In both cases there is nothing on workflow history and error report is also empty (it even cause an error "Report contains no data").

I'm sure that I didn't change anything in a workflow. The only think that I changed was an InfoPath form, but I only added there field "Created By", so I would see in calendar later who created this request. I couldn't see how this might affect workflow process.

I'm confused as I don't even know where to start searching for the solution. Why this might happen? Any ideas are very welcome!

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!!! This totally fixed my workflow! I had customized the emails that get sent with fields from the form. Once I removed those non-mandatory fields, it started working again! YAY!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was weird. In my list I have a multiple choice field which is not required. When it was blank my workflow was failing on start! This field was not involved in a workflow directly, I included it only in the email to approver. When I deleted it from an email everything was fine.